# Is it possible to use more than one hard disk in Linux?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

hi i had a question
I'm still quite new to Linux and I have a question
I have two storage units on my computer, an ssd on which I put Windows and a mechanical hard disk.
Is there a way to carve out a storage space from the ssd to put Linux in it, and carve out another large space from the mechanical hard disk to store files and various programs, whether games, programs, movies...etc?

Comment: Hello. Yes of course it is. I sense there is more to this question you have not asked.

Comment: You can use whatever your hardware will allow.. which is machines with double-digit count of drives for me..  The limit is your own PSU (*how much power can it provide*), your boxes firmware (*how many drives can it support*) etc.. ie. hardware limits the number of drives.  The limits to how you partition is on you & the partition-table you elect to use (*legacy* has a strict limit of primary partitions for example, but numerous extended.. you've not limited your question to any specific partition-table)

Comment: @guiverc You're not actually limited to physical devices within the box. [Network block devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device) are all that uncommon. You can also have external arrays that don't depend on the system's form factor or PSU. Not likely that a new contributor is going to use them however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use more than one hard disk in linux, as you can in any other operating system out there.

Yes, it is possible to "carve out" storage space to put linux on it. A drive contains partitions. A partition contains a file system. One can change the partitioning of the drive using a partition editor: creating or deleting partitions, resizing partitions, even moving partitions although that is a slow process that you should avoid.

If you want to install Ubuntu, and you do not have experience with partitioning etc, then just let the installer guide you. The installer can automatically "carve out" space on an SSD, and then continues automatically with the installation and setting up a dual boot, i.e., when you boot the system, it will ask you what operating system to boot.

Anyway, your question is very broad. This very brief answer is generic and only aimed to orient yourself a bit more and to increase your general understanding. Read yourself in a bit more for setting up a dual boot system on your SSD before you start.